# Many belongsTo on the same table Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, belongs-to

I'm a little disappointed... I'm trying to join my tables with belongsTo but I have a problem.

I have this table : party

Id -- day -- clown -- makeup1 -- makeup2 ...

clown, makeup1, makeup2 are foreign keys, reference to people table.

Peoples table:

Id -- name -- firstname ...

In my system the values of clown, makeup1 and makeup2 are IDs of people table.
This is good.

The problem is when I want to show the name of clown, makeup1 and makeup2.

I have the error

> Trying to get property of non-object

In my model I defined my relations like this :

```
public function people()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(People::class, 'clown', 'id');
}
public function makeup1()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(People::class, 'makeup1', 'id');
}
public function makeup2()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(People::class, 'makeup2', 'id');
}
```

In my view I show the clown like this :

```
{{ $defaut->people->name }}
```

It works but the other not.

```
{{ $defaut-> makeup1->name }}
{{ $defaut-> makeup2->name }}
```

-> don't work and show

> Trying to get property of non-object

I don't understand....

PS : My request in controller is

```
$defaults = Default::with('people')->with('makeup1')->with('makeup2')->get();
```

And this one works, I see the relations in var_dump().

```
<pre>Collection {#654 ▼
#items: array:1 [▼
0 => Default {#619 ▼
  #table: "defaults"
  #fillable: array:8 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:11 [▶]
  #original: array:11 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:3 [▼
    "people" => People {#655 ▶}
    "makeup1" => People {#687 ▶}
    "makeup2" => People {#719 ▼
      #fillable: array:7 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:10 [▶]
      #original: array:10 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
]
}
</pre>
Thank you for your advices
```

Comment: Please show the output of `@dd($default)` in the view right before you're trying to display names.

Comment: This the dd($default) at the bottom of my first post.

Comment: It looks like `dd($defaults)` which you run in a controller. Just make sure you're working with the same data in the view and not data which you get from some other action.

Comment: try to rename the function or field in the table (example `makeup1_id`)

Comment: Alexey Mezenin, in my view I have only $defauts like data.

Comment: Try debugging the queries to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !
To show the relation I have to write :

```
{{ $defaut->makeup1()->first()->name }}
```

Thank you